# How to use early stopping with imbalanced data?

Tags: regularization, validation

I'm wondering if it is theoretically sound to use a metric such as binary F1-score as part of my early stopping criteria in tuning a model during training. I'm working with a collection of binary classification tasks with varying levels of imbalance, some being very positive-class heavy and vice versa.

I notice that, for one task where I have an abundance of positive-class samples, I achieve a higher validation loss than on a task with very few positive-class samples. I'm assuming that this may reflect the imbalance but since I only care about the correct classification of positive-class samples, how can I make my early stopping more robust to reflect this?

I rarely see F1-score being used as part of early stopping criteria, am I right in assuming this is because it is a hard classification metric which makes F1-score sensitive to misclassification during the validation stage? I've considered something like accuracy but I know that this could be even more ineffective for my use case since my model could be reporting high accuracy that moreso reflects the correct classification of negative samples.

Alternatively, I've looked at computing the positive/negative ratio of training samples and weighting the loss function but I was more concerned with whether or not it was reliable to just maximise binary F1?

Comment: "Early stopping" may refer to criteria for analysis and unblinding based on information growth in group sequential trials. However it looks like you're referring to a convergence criterion for an iterative process. Validation, such as K-fold cross validation, uses a fixed number of splits on a sample to assess model performance metrics. Why would K-fold cross validation need "early stopping"?

Comment: I suggest studying proper accuracy scoring rules.

Comment: @AdamO I am referring to the metric used to determine when to stop training a model, using a hold-out validation set during training and not K-Fold. In the past, I have aimed to minimise validation loss and was wondering if it were more apt, in my use case, to stop training once the binary F1-score stops improving (maximising).